# Large numbers losing precision in SQLiteDB?

Tags: java, sql

I'm storing 0.00 decimal values as text in an SQLiteDB. I'm retrieving them by

```
"SELECT SUM(SUBSTR(amount, 1)) FROM record WHERE date BETWEEN '" +
    date1 + "' AND '" + date2 + "'";
```

Problem is when the numbers start getting up to 10000.00 there seems to be issues with precision.

Comment: What's the purpose of SUBSTR?

Comment: Missed that. I used to store the numbers with a $ in front. Oddly, it seems to work the same whether that is there or not.

Comment: AFAIK, SQliteDB use `double` to represent decimals. You should expect to see some rounding errors which you will need to handle.

Comment: You are most likely coming up against a limit in a 4 byte floating point number.  If the number is a dollar amount, any chance you can switch the column to be integer cents?   Then at least you'd be able to get to $20 million with perfect precision.

Comment: Substr(,1) is the same as Substr(,0) - the latter is supported but better to use the former. If you had leading $, you would have used substr(,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value has been turned into a REAL (has floating point issues).  One option is just to round it

```
"SELECT ROUND(SUM(SUBSTR(amount, 1)),2) FROM record WHERE date BETWEEN '"+date+"' AND '"+date2+"'";
```

Or use INTEGER maths, shifting the position by 2 decimals

```
"SELECT SUM(CAST(SUBSTR(amount, 1)*100 as INT))/100.0 FROM record WHERE date BETWEEN '"+date+"' AND '"+date2+"'";
```

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the database engine) has one of the following storage classes: **NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, BLOB**

[What you need to know about Floating Point maths](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)